# Update row if references is exist, otherwise delete using spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

Need guideline -

How to do hard delete when no reference is available and do soft delete when reference is available, this operation should be performed in a single method itself.

E.g. 
I have 1 master table and 3 transactional tables and the master reference is available in all 3 transactional tables. 
Now while deleting master row - I have to do the following: If master reference is available then update the master table row and if no master ref. is available delete the row.

I tried following so far.

**Service Implementation -**

```
public response doHardOrSoftDelete(Employee emp) {
    boolean flag = iMasterDao.isDataExist(emp);
    if(flag) {
        boolean result = iMasterDao.doSoftDelete(emp);
    } else {
        boolean result = iMasterDao.doHardDelete(emp);
    }
}
```

**Second Approach:**

As we know that while deleting a record if the reference is available then it throws **ConstraintViolationException** so simply we can catch it and check that caught exception is of type ConstraintViolationException or not, if yes then call doSoftDelete() method and return the response. So here you don't need to write method or anything to check the references. But I'm not sure whether it is the right approach or not. Just help me with it.

Here is what I tried again -

```
public Response deleteEmployee(Employee emp) {
    Response response = null;
    try{
    String status= iMasterDao.deleteEmployeeDetails(emp);
    if(status.equals("SUCCESS")) {
        response = new Response();
        response.setStatus("Success");
        response.setStatusCode("200");
        response.setResult("True");
        response.setReason("Record deleted successfully");
        return response;    
    }else {
        response = new Response();
        response.setStatus("Fail");
        response.setStatusCode("200");
        response.setResult("False");
    }
    }catch(Exception e){
        response = new Response();
         Throwable t  =e.getCause();
         while ((t != null) && !(t instanceof ConstraintViolationException)) {
            t = t.getCause();
         }
         if(t instanceof ConstraintViolationException){
            boolean flag = iMasterDao.setEmployeeIsDeactive(emp);
            if(flag) {
                 response.setStatus("Success");
                 response.setStatusCode("200");
                 response.setResult("True");
                 response.setReason("Record deleted successfully");
            }else{
                response.setStatus("Fail");
                response.setStatusCode("200");
                response.setResult("False");
            }
         }else {
             response.setStatus("Fail");
             response.setStatusCode("500");
             response.setResult("False");
             response.setReason("# EXCEPTION : " + e.getMessage()); 
         }
    }
    return response;
}
```

---

**Dao Implementation -**

```
public boolean isDataExist(Employee emp) {
    boolean flag = false;       
    List<Object[]> tbl1 = session.createQuery("FROM Table1 where emp_id=:id")
    .setParameter("id",emp.getId())
    .getResultList();

    if(!tbl1.isEmpty() && tbl1.size() > 0) {
        flag = true;
    }

    List<Object[]> tbl2 = session.createQuery("FROM Table2 where emp_id=:id")
    .setParameter("id",emp.getId())
    .getResultList();

    if(!tbl2.isEmpty() && tbl2.size() > 0) {
        flag = true;
    }

    List<Object[]> tbl3 = session.createQuery("FROM Table3 where emp_id=:id")
    .setParameter("id",emp.getId())
    .getResultList();

    if(!tbl3.isEmpty() && tbl3.size() > 0) {
        flag = true;
    }

    return flag;
}

public boolean doSoftDelete(Employee emp) {
    empDet = session.get(Employee.class, emp.getId());
    empDet .setIsActive("N");
    session.update(empDet);
}

public boolean doHardDelete(Employee emp) {
    empDet = session.get(Employee.class, emp.getId());
    session.delete(empDet);
}
```

No matter how many transactional tables will be added with master tbl reference, my code should do the operations(soft/hard delete) accordingly.

In my case, every time new transactional tables get added with a master reference I've do the checks, so Simply I want to skip the isDataExist() method and do the deletions accordingly, how can I do it in a better way?

Please help me with the right approach to do the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot of repeated code in the body of `isDataExist()` method which is both hard to maintain and hard to extend (if you have to add 3 more tables the code will double in size).
On top of that the logic is not optimal as it will go over all tables even if the result from the first one is enough to return `true`.

Here is a simplified version (please note that I haven't tested the code and there could be errors, but it should be enough to explain the concept):

```
public boolean isDataExist(Employee emp) {
    List<String> tableNames = List.of("Table1", "Table2", "Table3");

    for (String tableName : tableNames) {
        if (existsInTable(tableName, emp.getId())) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

private boolean existsInTable(String tableName, Long employeeId) {
    String query = String.format("SELECT count(*) FROM %s WHERE emp_id=:id", tableName);

    long count = (long)session
            .createQuery(query)
            .setParameter("id", employeeId)
            .getSingleResult();

    return count > 0;
}
```

`isDataExist()` contains a list of all table names and iterates over these until the first successful encounter of the required `Employee id` in which case it returns `true`. If not found in any table the method returns `false`.

`private boolean existsInTable(String tableName, Long employeeId)` is a helper method that does the actual search for `employeeId` in the specified `tableName`.
I changed the query to just return the count (0 or more) instead of a the actual entity objects as these are not required and there's no point to fetch them.

---

**EDIT** in response to the "Second approach"

Is the `Second Approach` meeting the requirements? 
If so, then it is a "right approach" to the problem. :)

I would refactor the `deleteEmployeeDetails` method to either return a `boolean` (if just two possible outcomes are expected) or to return a custom `Enum` as using a `String` here doesn't seem appropriate.

There is repeated code in `deleteEmployeeDetails` and this is never a good thing. You should separate the logic which decides the type of the `response` from the code that builds it, thus making your code easier to follow, debug and extend when required.

Let me know if you need a code example of the ideas above.

---

**EDIT #2**

Here is the sample code as requested.

First we define a `Status` `enum` which should be used as return type from `MasterDao`'s methods:

```java
public enum Status {
    DELETE_SUCCESS("Success", "200", "True", "Record deleted successfully"),
    DELETE_FAIL("Fail", "200", "False", ""),
    DEACTIVATE_SUCCESS("Success", "200", "True", "Record deactivated successfully"),
    DEACTIVATE_FAIL("Fail", "200", "False", ""),
    ERROR("Fail", "500", "False", "");

    private String status;
    private String statusCode;
    private String result;
    private String reason;

    Status(String status, String statusCode, String result, String reason) {
        this.status = status;
        this.statusCode = statusCode;
        this.result = result;
        this.reason = reason;
    }

    // Getters 
}
```

`MasterDao` methods changed to return `Status` instead of `String` or `boolean`:

```java
public Status deleteEmployeeDetails(Employee employee) {
    return Status.DELETE_SUCCESS; // or Status.DELETE_FAIL
}

public Status deactivateEmployee(Employee employee) {
    return Status.DEACTIVATE_SUCCESS; // or Status.DEACTIVATE_FAIL
}
```

Here is the new `deleteEmployee()` method:

```java
public Response deleteEmployee(Employee employee) {
    Status status;
    String reason = null;

    try {
        status = masterDao.deleteEmployeeDetails(employee);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (isConstraintViolationException(e)) {
            status = masterDao.deactivateEmployee(employee);
        } else {
            status = Status.ERROR;
            reason = "# EXCEPTION : " + e.getMessage();
        }
    }

    return buildResponse(status, reason);
}
```

It uses two simple utility methods (you can make these static or export to utility class as they do not depend on the internal state).

First checks if the root cause of the thrown exception is `ConstraintViolationException`:

```java
private boolean isConstraintViolationException(Throwable throwable) {
    Throwable root = throwable;
    while (root != null && !(root instanceof ConstraintViolationException)) {
        root = root.getCause();
    }
    return root != null;
}
```

And the second one builds the `Response` out of the `Status` and a `reason`:

```java
private Response buildResponse(Status status, String reason) {
    Response response = new Response();
    response.setStatus(status.getStatus());
    response.setStatusCode(status.getStatusCode());
    response.setResult(status.getResult());

    if (reason != null) {
        response.setReason(reason);
    } else {
        response.setReason(status.getReason());
    }

    return response;
}
```

If you do not like to have the `Status enum` loaded with default `Response` messages, you could strip it from the extra info:

```java
public enum Status {
    DELETE_SUCCESS, DELETE_FAIL, DEACTIVATE_SUCCESS, DEACTIVATE_FAIL, ERROR;
}
```

And use `switch` or `if-else` statements in `buildResponse(Status status, String reason)` method to build the response based on the `Status` type.

Comment: @MartingBG - Thank you for the reply and the optimal solution as well. The given solution optimizes the code but every time you map master entity with the transactional one you have to mention explicitly tables names. So to avoid this I tried another approach and it does works but I don't know whether it is the right approach or not, please help. Please see my edited post 'Second Approach' above.

Comment: Second approach is meeting my requirements and I'll be implementing the same. It would be great help if you could share code example for the above idea. 

Comment: You were 100% correct on the velocity arrays within the Particle constructor on a recent question.